# Youtube scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For the below code, I am having error in dislike line syntax

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}

def scrape_info(url):
   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
   title = s.find("span", class_="watch-title").get_text(strip=True)
   views = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s.find("div", class_="watch-view-count").get_text(strip=True))
   likes = s.find("span", class_="like-button-renderer").span.button.get_text(strip=True)
   dislikes = s.find("span", class_="dislike-button-renderer").span.button.get_text(strip=True)
   data = {'url': url, 'title':title, 'views':views, 'likes':likes }
   return data
```

```
ERROR- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

How can I add information like upload_date, number of dislikes, comments for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is because

```
dislikes = s.find("span", class_="dislike-button-renderer")
```

returns a `NoneType` object, also meaning the program didn't find anything that matches what you specified in the brackets. Instead, you can use an `if` statement:

```
dislikes = s.find("span", class_="dislike-button-renderer")
if dislikes:
    dislikes = dislikes.span.button.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: How can I add information like upload_date, number of dislikes, comments for the same?